# systemd StandardOutput redirection does not work with a systemd socket

Tags: linux, systemd, sockets, named-pipe

I have a systemd service like this (my-server.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server
After=syslog.target network-online.target my-server.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java myserver.jar
Sockets=my-server.socket
StandardOutput=fd:my-server.socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and an accompanying socket (my-server.socket):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server Output Socket

[Socket]
ListenFIFO=/run/my-server-log
SocketMode=0644
RemoveOnStop=false
```

I'm trying to basically have a named socket that I can simply attach to if I want to process the servers output. My problem is, that neither `tail -f /run/my-server-log` nor a python script that opens the same file ever outputs anything. The output is not shown in `systemd status` either, so I have no idea where it disappears to, but it does not seem to go into the named pipe like it should.

Am I missing or misunderstanding something here? As far as I see, this setup should work fine and [this person](https://serverfault.com/a/823973/343592) seems to have a similar setup working fine, so I'm not sure what the problem with my configuration is.

Comment: Is your goal to have the service running forever and only attach occassionally to "preview" the stdout, or is your goal to have the service be started on-demand as soon as you attach and stop on detach?

Comment: I'm trying to have the service run forever and then occasionally attach `tail` or some other script to the output (obviously the named pipe can only be read by one reader at the same time).